# Como descargar datos históricos con bucle for

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda

Hola requiero descargar datos históricos de años pasados a la fecha, pero solo estoy descargando un mes aún que cambie los valores en la api, como puedo usar un loop `for` para descargar de 1980 a la fecha en el siguiente código:

```py
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
r = requests.get(f'https://api.weather.com/v1/location/MMMX:9:MX/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apiKey}&units=e&startDate=20191201&endDate=20191231')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['observations'])
df['valid_time_gmt'] = df['valid_time_gmt'].map(lambda x: get_est_localtime(x).strftime(fmt))
df = df.groupby(by='valid_time_gmt').agg([min, max, np.mean])
print(df['temp'])
```

Comment: Iván, invalida la APIKEY que has puesto. No deberías hacerla pública.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le di solución con:

```py
data_frames = []
años = 2019 - 1973
año = 2019
for i in tqdm(range(0, años+1)):
    for j in range(1, 13):
        if len(str(13-j)) == 1:
            X = str(año - i)+"0"+ str(13-j) + "01"
            Y = str(año - i)+"0"+ str(13-j) + str(c.monthrange(año - i, 13 - j)[1])
        else:
            X = str(año - i) + str(13-j) + "01"
            Y = str(año - i) + str(13-j) + str(c.monthrange(año - i, 13 - j)[1])
```